# Generated installer creates shortcut that points to wrong executable

Tags: maven, netbeans, installation, 64-bit, netbeans-platform

I have created a Maven NetBeans Platform Application and I generate installers by running the "nbm build-installers" goal.  This creates an .exe that the user can then run to automatically install my application. (In an ordinary NBPA, this would be "Package as -> Installers". Both have the same issue)

After the user runs the installer, a shortcut is placed on the user's desktop. However, for Windows 7 and Windows 8 64-bit systems, the shortcut is pointing to the wrong binary. It points to the 32-bit version. For instance, if I have an app named "SampleApp", the shortcut points to something like "C:\Program Files\sampleapp\sampleapp.exe" and NOT "C:\Program Files\sampleapp\sampleapp64.exe" as it should.  Both of these binaries DO exist in this folder.

This issue is creating a real problem for us because the application calls out various DLLs that are architecture specific (32-bit version will use 32-bit dlls, 64-bit should use 64-bit dlls).

The installer needs to create a shortcut that points to the correct binary based on the user's Operating System architecture.

I have take the question from https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=246710 because I have the same problem.

Anyone knows how to fix this problem? Thanks

Comment: You should answer your question and accept it, instead of marking it as "solved" in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that there's a bug: the installer will always create a link to `sampleapp.exe` rather than to `sampleapp64.exe`. This doesn't have as much impact as one might expect. The exe file is really just a small launcher that kicks off a JVM process. If said JVM is 64 bit then that's what you are going to get regardless if the launcher `.exe` was actually a 32-bit binary. So most people would never see the problem in this bug. But you may be right if you are using external DLL then it may be a problem, dunno. I'll take your word for it and propose a solution.

Ok, so what really matters is the JVM you have available, not the OS itself. We can make a fairly safe assumption here: the JVM installing the application will also be the JVM which will eventually be running the application. This is at least always true if you a bundling the JRE and even in other cases it is a safe bet.

In order to fix you'll have to use your own version of [`ConfigurationLogic.java`](http://hg.netbeans.org/main-silver/file/tip/libs.nbi.ant/stub/ext/components/products/helloworld/src/org/mycompany/ConfigurationLogic.java) from the NBI stub because this is where the problem is.

In that file you'll see near the bottom

```java
 ...
 ...
     public static final String EXECUTABLE_WINDOWS =
            BIN_SUBDIR
            + ResourceUtils.getString(ConfigurationLogic.class, "CL.app.name") + ".exe"; // NOI18N
```

This needs to be fixed as follows:

```java
    private static String get64BitSuffix() {
        if (SystemUtils.isCurrentJava64Bit()) {
            return "64";
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }


...
...
    public static final String EXECUTABLE_WINDOWS =
        BIN_SUBDIR
        + ResourceUtils.getString(ConfigurationLogic.class, "CL.app.name") + get64BitSuffix() + get64BitSuffix() + ".exe"; // NOI18N
```

Now to the question about how to use your own `ConfigurationLogic.java` in a Maven-based project:  just google it.